# Alias resource file namespace in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, resources, namespaces

I have an ASP.net MVC 3 project with resource files setup in folders like:

```
/Resources/EntityName/Views/
/Resources/EntityName/Models/
```

This means the namespace to access the strongly typed resource values is:

`Resources.EntityName.Models.ModelA.Property1`

Visual studio gives a compile time error if I try to include the namespace "resources.xxx" and it won't allow the using alias syntax either.

Is there anyway to include or atleast alias the strongly typed namespace of a resource file like it was a normal namespace?

Comment: What error are you receiving? How are you trying to utilize these resources within your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no reason why you can't use one of these objects within a class:

```
using YourProject.Resources.EntityName.Models;
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was I was not specifying my projectname first

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this (not tested, just an idea)

```
public class myModelA : Resources.EntityName.Models.ModelA
{ /*Leave empty here, nothing to do*/ }
```

Then you may be able to call the shortest `myModelA` instead of the complete, verbose name of the resource. Watch out because you'll not be able to access `private` members of your original model if you inherit it like thi.